# Windows 8 laptop crashing while in sleep mode

Tags: windows

When I put my 2014 Razer Blade laptop to sleep, often when I wake it up it has crashed. I leave it plugged in all the time so I wouldn't expect it to be running out of power and dying, but I did notice it didn't have the glowing white light indiciating its sleeping. It isn't cleanly shutting down, which I know because Chrome tells me it didn't shut down properly. What might cause my computer to crash or to fail to use AC power while in sleep mode? I'm on Windows 8.1 home edition.

Comment: do you get a BSOD? if yes, share the dmp files from C:\windows\minidump

Comment: I never actually see a BSOD, but I do have dmp files in that location. Here's the most recent one: http://btetrud.com/files/011317-7828-01.dmp

Comment: latest BSOD seams to be caused by Virtualbox driver VBoxNetFlt.sys

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's really helpful, thanks! There does seem to be other reports of BSODs that lead back to VBoxNetFlt.sys . I'm updating my drivers to see if that fixes the problem.